# Sorting with using reflection linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to sort my records with using reflection

```
IQueryable<Container> containers = this.Repository.Containers;
foreach (var prop in typeof(Container).GetProperties())
{
    if (sortField.IndexOf(prop.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        containers = sortDir == "desc"
            ? containers.OrderByDescending(x => prop.GetValue(x, null))
            : containers.OrderBy(x => prop.GetValue(x, null));
    }
}
var total = await containers.CountAsync();
... Skip/Take actions ...
```

but I have error after executing this row `var total = await containers.CountAsync();`

```
The LINQ expression '(c) => (Unhandled parameter: __prop_2).GetValue(
    obj: c.Outer, 
    index: null)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: `containers` obviously comes from a database? Do you want the database to sort the records? Because that is what you are trying to do, but the db of course can't perform anything like reflection. The expressions you pass to `OrderBy` must be translatable into SQL. The other alternative is to materialize `containers` first (with `.ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` for example) and do the sorting client side.

Comment: In gerneral you should use a bool or enum to indicate your sort oder, string comparisions are bad for performance.

Comment: @RenéVogt Yes, `containers` comes from DB. I want to sort records at first then `Skip`/`Take` actions and in the end execute `.ToList()`. To avoid performance issues.

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/dynamic-linq-queries-with-expression-trees/